# Java caching with pub-sub and expiry and persistence

Tags: java, spring, caching, java-8, jms

I am looking to evaluate the simple solution to following problem.

Comment: Caching and simple are not usual in the same phrase. Once data starts to grow it will become insanely complex. See: [Why Cache Invalidation is Hard](https://yihui.org/en/2018/06/cache-invalidation/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a typical Spring solution for it. Some annotation such as import `org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;` and import `org.springframework.cache.annotation.CacheEvict;` that's all of you need.
And then you can declare any possible bean for caching, for example:

```
spring:
  cache:
    type: ${CACHE_TYPE:REDIS}
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 128MB
      max-request-size: 128MB
      enabled: true
```

for Redis and spring boot or simple bean with map.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you are talking two different things here. One is Cache which you can implement using Java API. JMS Frameworks for eg.., like Apache kafka is built on JMS API, Which can either be a Pub-Sub model or Point to Point model per your application Logic. For decision on when messages have to be deleted(like 5 days ago) or other application logic, ofcourse you can use an Observer Design Pattern. For Upstream-downstream Systems, You need JMS and for cache, you can use Java API.